# OpenPGP - en/decryption works in cmd but not in Perl script

Tags: perl, gnupg

The OpenPGP has been installed correctly and functions well. Below command works in Windows cmd:

```
gpg2 -r rept --encrypt myfile
```

However, while we are trying to automate above process using Perl system call:

```
system("gpg2 -r rept --encrypt myfile");
```

I got below error message: `gpg: rept: skipped: No public key`

Using `gpg2 --list-keys`, I indeed see the public key added. Could anyone provide with some insights of automating the OpenGPG processes?

Comment: Is the automation running under the same system user your developed under?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given only few information in the question I can only guess and my guess is that `rept` contains a `@` which gets interpreted because you have double quotes.

Apart from that please `use strict; use warnings;` so that you will find such errors early. Also use the multi-argument version of `system` so that no shell is involved, i.e. `system("gpg2","-r",....)`. Otherwise you might risk code execution if the `rept` or `myfile` is determined by user input.

Comment: That's exactly the case. The recipient name is actually an email address. Thanks for your suggestions of using strict and warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the issue of system accounts that Jens Erat mentioned it might be useful to add an explicit absolute path to the desired gpg config via the `--homedir` parameter. Might be that the Windows version of gpg is a bit crippled in this respect and fails to find the keys if started from a different directory.

Depending on what you want to do with the encrypted data you could also have a look at some modules: I've had good experiences with `Crypt::OpenPGP` (although being pure Perl it's quite slow), and `Crypt::PGPSimple` looks like it would do what you want using an external gpg executable.

Comment: We would like to keep installed Perl modules to minimum. As far as I understand, even though we installed Crypt module, we do still need OpenGPG software, right?

Comment: `Crypt::PGPSimple` is indeed just a wrapper for calling the external gpg binary. `Crypt::OpenPGP` does all the OpenPGP stuff in Perl and oesn't require gpg, however it has a whole bunch of dependencies that implement the actual crypto.

Comment: This is truly helpful. Appreciated it.